# AVD crashes my computer all the time during shutdown in Android Studio

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, android-virtual-device

As the title suggests AVD crashes my computer all the time during shutdown in the new updated version of Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2. I have no clue what is causing it and does anyone else experience the same?

best regards.

The android studio is updated

Comment: What OS (Windows/Linux/macOS and which version)? What hardware do you have (CPU model and RAM size)?